# port closed but iptables say open

Tags: iptables, firewall

I am using ubuntu 20.04 vps. I was trying to open a port like 4000. Server's ufw is inactive. command iptables -L shows port 4000 is accepting tcp connection .But I neither can ping it or checking online sasys port is closed.Any other probability. I am group user with sudo privileged, I am not the root though.[image][image]

Comment: Is there a router between you and the Internet? Then that is probably serving as a firewall.

Comment: I am using a paid vps,I've never seen  any router issue for last two years in vps

Comment: What is the output of `sudo lsof -i -P -n | grep LISTEN`?  Even if the port is open it still needs an app listening on that port.

Comment: @Terrance  https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/p/p7VXgFKH8D/

Comment: @Terrance I dont see port 4000 there

Comment: You have to have something listening on the port in order for it to show up.  If you are expecting FTP or something on that port you will have to configure the application to use that port.  Otherwise the system does not know what to do with an open port is nothing is listening so it will show that it is closed.

Comment: I am running a nodejs app,which is listening to port lcalhost:3000 , then I used apache to proxy that localhost:3000 to myip:4000   , apache .conf file >>> https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/p/mjCfkwRtHr/

Comment: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/bind.html